# Want to learn Unreal Engine for Augmented Reality

Tags: augmented-reality, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I want to learn Unreal Engine for Augmented Reality. I mean what should be the starting point? Should I start from Actor class, blueprints etc? What path should I follow? Any good resources, Udemy etc.?

Answer (score 2):

First of all if you are a Complete Beginner then you should know the basics of unreal engine first, for that watch this Video - [https://youtu.be/UVTzVtxxgE0](https://Unreal%20Engine%205%20Beginner%20Tutorial:%20Getting%20Started)

Then After getting familiar with the Engine itself(or if you are already) you can do a course of Augmented Reality inside Unreal Engine through Platforms like Udemy, Cousera and many more.

There are not many resources available online for learning AR in Unreal Engine so this Unreal Documentation might come in handy - [https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/SharingAndReleasing/XRDevelopment/AR/HandheldAR/AROverview/](https://Augmented%20Reality%20Using%20Unreal%20Engine%20Overview)

Watch this Youtube Video for more Reference related to Augmented Reality and its Applications using Unreal Engine - [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3i1dL6WTI-Y](https://Making%20Augmented%20Reality%20in%20UE5)